# Count to 100 in Danish

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, counting, natural-language

Print all the numbers from 0-100 in the right order using the Danish way of counting

## How they count

- Like English, they have dedicated words for 0-20, 30, 40 and 100
- Instead of saying `twenty-one` and `twenty-two`, they say `one and twenty` and `two and twenty`
- Starting with fifty they say multiples of 10 as n*20

  ```
  50 = half third times twenty = half way to the 3rd multiple of 20
  60 = three times twenty
  70 = half fourth times twenty
  80 = four times twenty
  90 = half fifth times twenty
  ```

  So for instance, 55 would be `five and half third times twenty`.

## Expected output

```
zero
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
thirteen
fourteen
fifteen
sixteen
seventeen
eighteen
nineteen
twenty
one and twenty
two and twenty
three and twenty
four and twenty
five and twenty
six and twenty
seven and twenty
eight and twenty
nine and twenty
thirty
one and thirty
two and thirty
three and thirty
four and thirty
five and thirty
six and thirty
seven and thirty
eight and thirty
nine and thirty
forty
one and forty
two and forty
three and forty
four and forty
five and forty
six and forty
seven and forty
eight and forty
nine and forty
half third times twenty
one and half third times twenty
two and half third times twenty
three and half third times twenty
four and half third times twenty
five and half third times twenty
six and half third times twenty
seven and half third times twenty
eight and half third times twenty
nine and half third times twenty
three times twenty
one and three times twenty
two and three times twenty
three and three times twenty
four and three times twenty
five and three times twenty
six and three times twenty
seven and three times twenty
eight and three times twenty
nine and three times twenty
half fourth times twenty
one and half fourth times twenty
two and half fourth times twenty
three and half fourth times twenty
four and half fourth times twenty
five and half fourth times twenty
six and half fourth times twenty
seven and half fourth times twenty
eight and half fourth times twenty
nine and half fourth times twenty
four times twenty
one and four times twenty
two and four times twenty
three and four times twenty
four and four times twenty
five and four times twenty
six and four times twenty
seven and four times twenty
eight and four times twenty
nine and four times twenty
half fifth times twenty
one and half fifth times twenty
two and half fifth times twenty
three and half fifth times twenty
four and half fifth times twenty
five and half fifth times twenty
six and half fifth times twenty
seven and half fifth times twenty
eight and half fifth times twenty
nine and half fifth times twenty
one hundred
```

## Rules

- You may use any separator to separate the numbers
- Due to a typo in the original specification, you may use `forth` instead of `fourth`.
- You may write a function or write to std-out
- Standard loopholes apply
- This is codegolf; shortest code in bytes win!

Comment: [Related.](http://satwcomic.com/just-a-number)

Comment: Why all the spaces? 55 is *femoghalvtredsindstyve* in Danish, **not** *fem og halv tred sinds tyve*.

Comment: The expected output looks decidedly non-Danish to me. (And 55 is _femoghalvtreds_, not _femoghalvtredsinstyve_ unless you're being deliberately archaic).

Comment: @Adám I decided to use English rather than Danish words to make the challenge more accessible, and we don't contract words in English.

Comment: @BlackCap: Some words do become contracted over time. For instance, it is *[screenshot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screenshot#Noun)*, not *screen shot*.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35435/29750)

Comment: Is printing in list-form also valid? E.g.: `[zero, one, two,...]`

Comment: @QBrute Yes, or you may just create a function that returns the list

Comment: English used to be like this. You know the nursery rhyme *Sing a Song of Sixpence*? "Four and twenty blackbirds, baked in a pie."

Comment: Not to mention our expected lifespan of 'three score and ten' years...

Comment: looks like German, which also counts "one and twenty"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you are right that german, like danish, is also flipped compared to english. Germans operate in multiplies of 10 unlike danish which uses multiplies of 20.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>347</s> <s>336</s> <s>326</s> <s>325</s> 308 bytes

```js
for(a=btoa`...`.split(i=0);i<101;i++)alert(i<13?a[i]:i<20?(a[i]||a[i-10])+"teen":i>99?"one hundred":(i%10?a[i%10]+" and ":"")+(i<30?"twenty":i<40?"thirty":i<50?"forty":(i%20>9?"half "+["third","forth","fifth"][i/20-2|0]:a[i/20|0])+" times twenty"))
```

Before running, replace the `...` with the result of running this code:

```js
atob("zero0one0two0three0four0five0six0seven0eight0nine0ten0eleven0twelve0thir00fif000eigh")
```

Or you could just use the uncompressed version:

```js
for(a="zero0one0two0three0four0five0six0seven0eight0nine0ten0eleven0twelve0thir00fif000eigh".split(i=0);i<101;i++)alert(i<13?a[i]:i<20?(a[i]||a[i-10])+"teen":i>99?"one hundred":(i%10?a[i%10]+" and ":"")+(i<30?"twenty":i<40?"thirty":i<50?"forty":(i%20>9?"half "+["third","forth","fifth"][i/20-2|0]:a[i/20|0])+" times twenty"))
```

Still probably not optimal. 11 bytes saved in part by @Titus.

Comment: I was wrong. that´s a reasonable way to golf the exceptions.

Comment: -7 bytes: `(x%20>9?"half ":"")+[third,forth,fifth][x/20-2.5|0]` instead of `(x%20>9?"half "+[third,forth,fifth][x/20-2.5|0]:f(x/20|0))`

Comment: @Titus If I understand what you mean, that generates incorrect output for 60, 61, ..., 69, 80, 81... (e.g. `third times twenty` instead of `three times twenty`)

Comment: Oh I was missing that difference. You´re right. But get rid of the recursion; that will make way for a little more golfing.

Comment: @Titus Thanks for the tip. I didn't notice it, but recursion was actually saving me exactly 0 bytes over non-recursion. I've switched and golfed some more now.

Comment: `_` as seperator should give another 13 bytes.

Comment: Ok, you finally beat me. :) The overhead for base64_encoding in PHP is larger than what I would save on the string.

Comment: @Titus I don't understand what you mean about using `_` as separator. Do you mean using it in `a`, or in the output?

Comment: Any of `>?<{:@ \[]^\`_|;-},~)*&%!'"($#.` as a word delimiter will give you a smaller `atob` result. But it may contain bytes that you can´t put in an editor.

Comment: @Titus As far as I'm aware, all of those characters are illegal in `atob` inputs.

Answer (score 14):

## [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier), 7028 bytes

*The bounty will go to [**Paul Schmitz's answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92812/59035)*

This was [golfed programmatically](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10029/auto-golfing-good-or-bad) using issacg's [golfing program](https://ideone.com/Wjjz8M)

```
122a101a114a-3a10a111ava-9a10a116a+3a-8a10a116a104a114a101aa10a102a+9a+6a-3a10a102a+3a118a101a10a115a105a120a10a115a101a118a101a+9a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a10a110a-5a+5a-9a10a116a101a+9a10a101a+7a-7a118a101a+9a10a116a+3a101a+7a118a101a10a116a104a^a+9a+2a101aa+9a10a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a101aa+9a10a102a+3a-3a116a101aa+9a10a115a105a120a-4a101aa+9a10a115a101a118a101a+9a+6a101aa+9a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a101aa+9a10a110a-5a+5a-9a116a101aa+9a10a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a104a117a-7a100a114a101ava
```

[**Try it online!**](http://fourier.tryitonline.net/#code=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)

Comment: Here's a suggestion: simply print the output.  It consists of 1989 characters that use the same number of bytes.

Comment: @DavidC As far as I know this *is* how you "simply print the output" in Fourier. There are no string literals if that's what you meant.

Comment: @DavidC Martin is right, strings don't exist in Fourier

Comment: My goodness, very strange language it seems!

Comment: I got 7020 bytes. http://pastebin.com/WGtHSGFT

Comment: @PaulSchmitz Post it as an answer so I can award the bounty

Comment: @BetaDecay http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92812/59035

Comment: @BetaDecay Thank you for the bounty.

Comment: @PaulSchmitz My pleasure :)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), non-competing

I decided to do what the title actually asked, and counted to 100 på dansk. This is based on [ETHproductions' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92657/count-to-100-in-danish/92668#92668). It is 292 bytes (286 if you use alert instead)

```js
for(a="nul0en0to0tre0fire0fem0seks0syv0otte0ni0ti0elleve0tolv0tret0fjor0fem0seks0syt0at0nit".split(i=0);i<101;i++)console.log(i<13?a[i]:i<20?(a[i])+"ten":i>99?"hundrede":(i%10?a[i%10]+"og":"")+(["tyve","tredive","fyrre","halvtreds","tres","halvfjerds","firs","halvfems"][Math.floor(i/10)-2]))
```

Comment: To be fair, you should append *instyve* to every number that ends in *s*.

Comment: @Adám: Why so? The _-sinstyve_ is etymology, not actual Danish as currently spoken.

Comment: Yeah, but the English OP does include it, otherwise it should say *55 would be `five and half third t`*.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, <s>397</s> <s>375</s> <s>372</s> <s>381</s> <s>386</s> 365 bytes

This was too funny to be ignored. It can possibly be golfed further.

```
zero_<?=join(_,$a=[one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen])._;foreach([twenty,thirty,forty]as$t)for($i=-2;$i++<8;)echo($i<0?'':$c[]="$a[$i] and ").$t._;foreach([third,three,fourth,four,fifth]as$k=>$t)for($i=-2;$i++<8;)echo$c[$i],($k&1?'':'half '),"$t times twenty_";?>one hundred
```

- It uses underscore as the separator
- 10 to 19 are still hardcoded; any way to compute them doesn´t give as much as the join.

Answer (score 8):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 434 bytes

```
/(/\/\///D/\/7(7/ and (2/twenty(4/ times (_/half ([/42
(&/three(;/thir()/four(!/fort($/_fifth[(#/seven(^/eight(@D;ty
(%D_!h[(*D_;d[(-/nine(`D!y
(F/five(T/teen
(O/one(X/six(GD&[(HD)[(ID2
(Y/two(AD$/zero
O
Y
&
)
F
X
#
^
-
ten
eleven
twelve
;T)TfifTXT#T^een
-T2
OIYI&I)IFIXI#I^I-I;ty
O@Y@&@)@F@X@#@^@-@!y
O`Y`&`)`F`X`#`^`-`_;d42
O*Y*&*)*F*X*#*^*-*&[OGYG&G)GFGXG#G^G-G_!h[O%Y%&%)%F%X%#%^%-%)[OHYH&H)HFHXH#H^H-H$OAYA&A)AFAXA#A^A-AO hundred
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=)

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica <s>251 238</s> 230 bytes

This now presents the output in the format of a list, to save 8 more bytes.

```
c@s_:=s<>" times twenty";f@n_:=Which[n<21∨{30,40,100}~MemberQ~n,IntegerName@n,n==50,c@"half third",n==60,c@"three",n==70,c@"half forth",n==80,c@"four",n==90,c@"half fifth",3>2,NumberExpand@n/.{t_,u_}:>f@u<>" plus "<>f@t];f/@0~Range~100
```

Comment: I'm really jealous of that IntegerName function

Comment: Yeah, it does a good amount of the work.   `NumberExpand` is also useful for decomposing a number (in any base). `NumberExpand[943]-> {900,40,3}

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>308</s> <s>291</s> 285 bytes

```
w=words;q x=map(++x);m=w"thir four fif six seven eigh nine";t=w"zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve"++q"teen"m++q"ty"(do b<-"twen":take 2m++q" times twen"["half third",t!!3,"half fourth",t!!4,"half fifth"];b:q b(q" and ".take 9$tail t))++["one hundred"]
```

**Readable version:**

```
w   = words
m   = w "thir four fif six seven eigh nine"
q x = map (++x)

t = w "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve"
 ++ q "teen" m 
 ++ q "ty" (do b <- "twen" : take 2 m
                     ++ q " times twen"
                          ["half third",t!!3,"half fourth",t!!4,"half fifth"]
               b:q b(q" and ".take 9$tail t)
           )
 ++ ["one hundred"]
```

Also 285

```
w=words;m=w"thir four fif six seven eigh nine";x!l=map(++x)l
t  = w"zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve"
  ++ "teen"!m
  ++ "ty"!(
  do x<-"twen":take 2m++" times twen"!
         ["half third",t!!3,"half fourth",t!!4,"half fifth"]
     x:x!(" and "!take 9(tail t)))
  ++ ["one hundred"]
```

It might not look much different, but it represents hours of factorization that eventually brought me full circle. I think I have done this before..

Comment: Damn, Nordic-related challenge and so there already is a fp solution I can hardly improve on (fp being quite popular in the Nordics, no?)

Comment: @LeifWillerts I don't know anyone else who do fp, nor do they teach it in schools- sadly. You could try Lisp, it has `format nil "~R"` which converts numbers to their English text representation

Comment: Why do you suggest that Lisp?

Well, I have been taught FP in Germany by a professor who had spent a lot of time at Chalmers in Sweden, and in here in Copenhagen they teach it on quite a high level and there is an active community in the city. Erlang was famously developed by Ericsson in Sweden. Where are you and what do you do?

Comment: @LeifWillerts I'm in Norway, just graduated from high-school and decided to work in webdev for a year before going to uni. I've obviously checked what options I have, and none of them are fp.
None of my colleges or friends had even heard of functional programming before they met me..

Also, I suggested Lisp because half of my bytes come from storing numbers in strings, and you could get around that in Lisp.

Comment: Why is it non-competing? Just because you are OP doesn't mean non-competing AFAIK. Mods correct me if I'm wrong though...

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Can someone confirm that? I thought competing in my own challenge sounded a bit cheesy..

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>445</s> <s>426</s> <s>452</s> <s>449</s> <s>444</s> 439 bytes

```c
*t[]={0,0,"twenty","thirty","fourty",[10]="one hundred","third","fourth","fifth"},*o[101]={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};i,p;main(j){for(;i<'e';i++)p=i%10,o[i]?puts(o[i]):printf("%s%s%s%s%s%s\n",p?o[p]:t,p?" and ":t,!t[j]&j%2?"half ":t,t[j]?t:j%2?t[j/2+9]:o[j/2],t[j]?t:" times ",t[j=i/10]?:t[2]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFRboMwEESvQi3RQKAK8Bco4iCuPxCYsIjYljFJ24iz07UBVZa8z7M7o5XcfNyaZl3PhrLylcRJTMyTC/NDEHrQDjo5O6BpwkoiBff6WbSat/tQe8z0FqDDusRnieMphpJfriU20Gfnn9K5NOe7y3ke9jXBt735gwusHG69wSpgM27iuHdxy9GZ3JbcaW6HHXGLjTD0IGvd2YVvaPMdLgXEqrjXIIIhfHVSBwV8nvipgCgKVQl@msSSAqvUbKbAUpgrDcJ0AfGn//OFqaqSVLHcIBCvFq1HkN8MHdj74GcV6euxc5qVKpNbEfGSRVeWSwvsaBHPwJ1PHrFCCRf8hCo3NGNhsazrHw)

<s>19</s> <s>22</s> 27 bytes shaved off thanks to @ceilingcat, but 26 bytes were added again, 3 to prevent a segfault (o[] really has to have 101 entries), and upon checking the rules again I noticed we had to print out all numbers from 0 to 100, not just provide a function that printed one number.

Ungolfed:

````c
char *t[] = {0, 0, "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "one hundred", "third", "fourth", "fifth"};
char *o[101] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int p = 0;

main()
{
  for(; i < 101; i++) {
    p = i % 10;
    if(o[i])
        puts(o[i]);
    else
        printf("%s%s%s%s%s%s\n",
               p ? o[p] : "",
               p ? " and " : "",
               !t[j] & j % 2 ? "half " : "",
               t[j] ? "" : j % 2 ? t[j / 2 + 9] : o[j / 2],
               t[j] ? "" : " times ",
               t[j = i / 10] ? : t[2]
        );
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>333</s> <s>328</s> 321 bytes

@ETHproductions´s expression ported to PHP and golfed down. I am surprised that PHP can beat JavaScript *without any builtins*.

I guess the mightiest builtins are the implicit typecasts:

- I need no quotes for most of the strings, that alone is worth 12 bytes;
- and it allows me to use an array directly instead of splitting a string.
- the array indexing is implicitly typecasting any floats to integer, saving 6 bytes.

**BUT:** I need `$`s (21 of them) to tell PHP that it´s a variable.

So it´s still unclear where the 15 bytes actually come from. I didn´t golf away that much. Or did I? ETH caught up.

```
<?$a=[zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,'',fifteen,'','',eighteen];for($n=-1;$n++<99;)echo$n>19?($n%10?$a[$n%10].' and ':'').($n>49?($n%20>9?"half ".[third,forth,fifth][$n/20-2.5]:$a[$n/20]).' times twenty':[twen,thir,'for'][$n/10-2].ty):($a[$n]?:$a[$n%10].teen),_;?>one hundred
```

Comment: Beating you now ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Fourier, 7020 bytes

```
122a101~za114a-3a10a111ava-9a10a116a+3a-8a10a116a104a114a101aa10a102a+9a+6a-3a10a102a+3a118a101a10a115a105a120a10a115a101a118a101a+9a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a10a110a-5a+5a-9a10a116a101a+9a10a101a+7a-7a118aza+9a10a116a+3a101a+7a118a101a10a116a104a^a+9a+2a101aa+9a10a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a101aa+9a10a102a+3a-3a116a101aa+9a10a115a105a120a-4a101aa+9a10a115a101a118aza+9a+6a101aa+9a10aza+4a-2a^a116a101aa+9a10a110a-5a+5a-9a116a101aa+9a10a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114azaa32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118aza32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a^a+9a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+3a+2a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a116a104a^a+9a100a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a116a104a114a101aa32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+9a+6a-3a+2a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a102a+9a+6a-3a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a+3a-8a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a116a104a114a101aa32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+9a+6a-3a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a102a+3a118a101a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a105a120a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a115a101a118a101a+9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a101a+4a-2a^a116a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a110a-5a+5a-9a32a97a110a100a32a104a97a108a-6a32a102a+3a-3a116a104a32a116a105a+4a-8a115a32a116a+3a101a+9a+6a+5a10a111ava-9a32a104a117a-7a100a114a101ava
```

This is an improved version of Beta Decays program.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>127</s> <s>123</s> <s>120</s> 115 bytes

```
“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š—¿áÓÁÏ‰ª†ìdßàŒšdï¿dŸ¯een¥Šd“¤'…§:#©`…«¹¿œÖƒ#“‰ª„í¦ƒ†ì³ä“#ε…ÿ„Æ«¹NÈi„Š£ ì]«vyTG®Nè'€ƒ‚yª]„€µ°¡»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY@xasJgFIVfRcjgO/QF3JxchVaSwUWHQsHt10HcCrFUENGkjdHGWIVSUDoEzuF3EXyI@yLpf4PbvZzvnHtP//mp0w3KUswCMWcyyvErZi7mQ8ySezER8@uYExvamAcU9oQD1jYS84aCMacc8lXMEVmF@lwxUtZX2Fc6CHpq8PVCUheTYvPg4etRpx3OLnLK90voOf2e4@4ivYRVIH6YOMW7ua9SFiqO1dbkpOsWG@GzxryN3cug1cB3k9u666Dm@QBZ2yFVJRwR468s/wE)

```
“¡× (...) Šd“         # dictionary string "zero one two ... sixd sevend eighteen nined"
¤                     # get the last letter ("d") without popping 
 '…§                  # dictionary string "teen"
    :                 # replace (changes all "d" to "teen" in the initial string)
     #                # split on spaces
      ©               # save this list to the register
       `              # dump all items on the stack
…«¹¿œÖƒ               # dictionary string "twenty thirty fourty"
       #              # split on spaces
“‰ª„í¦ƒ†ì³ä“          # dictionary string "third three fourth four fifth"
            #         # split on spaces
ε              ]      # for each:
 …ÿ„Æ«¹               #  append " times twenty"
       NÈi     ]      #  if the iteration count is even:
          „Š£ ì       #   prepend "half "
                «     # merge those two lists ([20, 30, 40] and [50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
v            ]        # for y in this list of names:
 y                    #  put y on the stack
  TG         ]        #  for N from 1 to 9:
    ®Nè               #   get the Nth element in the register
       '€ƒ‚           #   append "and"
           yª         #   append y
„€µ°¡                 # dictionary string "one hundred"
     »                # join the stack with newlines
```

Comment: That's 230 bytes, with 115 wide (16-bit) characters.

Comment: @JohnTromp no, that’s 115 8-bit characters. See [05AB1E’s codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).

Comment: Ok; I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 346 bytes

Only a small idea to ETHproductions' solution:
Replace `f(..)` with `a[..]` to be able to call `f` recursively to concat the output.

```
f=x=>(a="1one1two1three1four1five1six1seven1eight1nine1ten1eleven1twelve1thir11fif111eigh".split(1),x<1?"zero":f(x-1)+(x<13?a[x]:x<20?(a[x]||a[x-10])+"teen":x>99?"one hundred":(x%10?a[x%10]+" and ":"")+(x<50?"twen1thir1for".split(1)[x/10-2|0]+"ty":(x%20>9?"half "+"third1forth1fifth".split(1)[x/20-2.5|0]:a[x/20|0])+" times twenty")))+"\n"
f(100)
```

Still far away from optimal...

Answer (score 3):

## Java <s>8</s> 7, <s>512</s> 490 + 19(import) bytes

Needs an import `import java.util.*;`

```java
<T>void y(List<T>l,T...a){for(T t:a)l.add(t);}List x(){String b="teen",c="twenty",d="half ",e=" times "+c;String[]a={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"},f={c,"thirty","fourty",d+"third"+e,a[3]+e,d+"fourth"+e,a[4]+e,d+"fifth"+e};List<String>g=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));y(g,"ten","eleven","twelve","thir"+b,a[4]+b,"fif"+b,a[6]+b,a[7]+b,"eigh"+b,a[9]+b);for(String h:f){y(g,h);for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)y(g,(a[i]+" and "+h));}y(g,"one hundred");return g;}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```java
<T> void y(List<T> l, T... a) {
    for (T t : a) {
        l.add(t);
    }
}

List x() {
    String b = "teen", c = "twenty", d = "half ", e = " times " + c;
    String[] a = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"},
        f = {c, "thirty", "fourty", d + "third" + e, a[3] + e, d + "fourth" + e, a[4] + e, d + "fifth" + e};
    List<String> g = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    y(g, "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thir" + b, a[4] + b, "fif" + b, a[6] + b, a[7] + b, "eigh" + b, a[9] + b);

    for (String h : f) {
        y(g, h);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            y(g, (a[i] + " and " + h));
        }
    }

    y(g, "one hundred");
    return g;
}
```

To run this, simply call `<instance>.x();`. This now returns the list containing all numbers.

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/z3EJPU)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>359</s> <s>349</s> 345 Bytes

```python
a='one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split()
c=['ten','eleven','twelve']+[i+'teen'for i in['thir',a[3],'fif',a[5],a[6],'eigh',a[8]]]
p=' times twenty'
h='half '
x=[p[7:],'thirty','forty',h+'third'+p,a[2]+p,h+'forth'+p,a[3]+p,h+'fifth'+p]
f=['zero']+a+c
for i in x:f+=[i];f+=[b+' and '+i for b in a] 
for i in f+['one hundred']:print i
```

### Explanation:

Create a list of the first 9 numbers.
Create a list of the next 10 numbers.
Create a list of the endings - `twenty`, `thirty`, `forty`, `half third times twenty` etc
Join the first two lists with `zero`
Append to the list each of the numbers from 50 onwards.
Print out list

Ungolfed code:

```python
firstNumbers=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
teenNumbers=['ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen']
endings=['twenty','thirty','forty','half third times twenty','three times twenty','half forth times twenty','four times twenty','half fifth times twenty']
joined=['zero']+firstNumbers+teenNumbers
for ending in endings:
    joined.append(ending)
    for number in firstNumbers:
        joined.append(number + 'and' + ending)
joined.append('one hundred')
for line in joined:
    print line
```

Comment: Some golfing: teen line - remove space after `in`; move `q` into the only place it is used; do `for i in f+['one hundred']:print i`

Comment: @JonathanAllan The score actually measured it with the q='and' - I'd noticed, just forgot to change it here! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, with num2words, 206 bytes

Even with num2words it takes quite a few bytes!

This is a full program.

```
from num2words import num2words as w
for i in range(1,101):d=i/10;e=w(i).split('-');print' and '.join(e[1:]+[10>d>4 and((d%2 and'half '+{5:'third',7:'forth',9:'fifth'}[d]or w(d/2))+' times twenty')or e[0]])
```

Here is a mocked version on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/2jXL27)
(By mocked I mean that since the online interpreter does not have `num2words` I replaced `w` with a `lambda` which looks up `num2word`'s output in a list)

ungolfed and with 'fourth' rather than the allowed 'forth' (which saves a byte):

```
from num2words import num2words
for i in range(1,101):
    d = i / 10 # i div 10
    e = num2words(i).split('-') # i in English words with a "-" separator, split into parts
    if d > 4 and d < 10:
        if d % 2:
            p = 'half '+ {5:'third', 7:'fourth', 9:'fifth'}[d] + ' times twenty'
        else:
            p = num2words(d / 2) + ' times twenty'
    else:
        p = e[0]
    print' and '.join(e[1:]+[p])
```

Note that the separator used by `num2words(100)` is a space, whereas for the other numbers it is a "-", so we don't need to do anything fancy for that case other than stop it from being "five times twenty".

---

**Aside**

If the challenge were to actually produce the numbers in Danish one could take the lang_DK.py from the [github page](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/blob/master/num2words/lang_DK.py) and use:

```
from num2words import*
[num2words(i,lang='dk')for i in range(1,101)]
```

for 68 bytes, yielding:

```
['et', 'to', 'tre', 'fire', 'fem', 'seks', 'syv', 'otte', 'ni', 'ti', 'elleve', 'tolv', 'tretten', 'fjorten', 'femten', 'seksten', 'sytten', 'atten', 'nitten', 'tyve', 'enogtyve', 'toogtyve', 'treogtyve', 'fireogtyve', 'femogtyve', 'seksogtyve', 'syvogtyve', 'otteogtyve', 'niogtyve', 'tredive', 'enogtredive', 'toogtredive', 'treogtredive', 'fireogtredive', 'femogtredive', 'seksogtredive', 'syvogtredive', 'otteogtredive', 'niogtredive', 'fyrre', 'enogfyrre', 'toogfyrre', 'treogfyrre', 'fireogfyrre', 'femogfyrre', 'seksogfyrre', 'syvogfyrre', 'otteogfyrre', 'niogfyrre', 'halvtreds', 'enoghalvtreds', 'tooghalvtreds', 'treoghalvtreds', 'fireoghalvtreds', 'femoghalvtreds', 'seksoghalvtreds', 'syvoghalvtreds', 'otteoghalvtreds', 'nioghalvtreds', 'treds', 'enogtreds', 'toogtreds', 'treogtreds', 'fireogtreds', 'femogtreds', 'seksogtreds', 'syvogtreds', 'otteogtreds', 'niogtreds', 'halvfjerds', 'enoghalvfjerds', 'tooghalvfjerds', 'treoghalvfjerds', 'fireoghalvfjerds', 'femoghalvfjerds', 'seksoghalvfjerds', 'syvoghalvfjerds', 'otteoghalvfjerds', 'nioghalvfjerds', 'firs', 'enogfirs', 'toogfirs', 'treogfirs', 'fireogfirs', 'femogfirs', 'seksogfirs', 'syvogfirs', 'otteogfirs', 'niogfirs', 'halvfems', 'enoghalvfems', 'tooghalvfems', 'treoghalvfems', 'fireoghalvfems', 'femoghalvfems', 'seksoghalvfems', 'syvoghalvfems', 'otteoghalvfems', 'nioghalvfems', 'ethundrede']
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (using `rev` and `sed`), <del>299</del> 276  bytes

I'm using bash's curly braces-expansion. However the braces are expanded in the wrong order, so I print all the words in reverted order and then fix the order of the letters using `rev`. After that, I still need some adjustments using `sed`:

```
printf '%s\n' orez {,{neet,yt{newt,riht,rof},ytnewt\ semit\ {drihtX,eerht,htruofX,ruof,htfifX}}Y}{,eno,owt,eerht,ruof,evif,xis,neves,thgie,enin} derdnuh\ eno |rev |sed -r 's,^Yte,t,;s,^Y,,;12s,.*,eleven,;13s,o.*,elve,;1,20{s,reeY,ir,;s,veY,f,;s,(t|)Y,,};s,Y, and ,;s,X,half ,'
```

A bit less unreadable:

```
printf '%s\n' orez {,{neet,yt{newt,riht,rof},\
ytnewt\ semit\ {drihtX,eerht,htruofX,ruof,htfifX}}Y}\
{,eno,owt,eerht,ruof,evif,xis,neves,thgie,enin} \
    derdnuh\ eno \
    |rev \
    |sed -r 's,^Yte,t,;
            s,^Y,,;
            12s,.*,eleven,;
            13s,o.*,elve,;
            1,20{s,reeY,ir,;s,veY,f,;s,(t|)Y,,};
            s,Y, and ,;
            s,X,half ,'
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP , 318 Bytes

```php
for($i=~0;$i++<100;)echo([0=>zero,10=>ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,15=>fifteen,18=>eighteen,100=>"one hundred"][$i]??["",one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][$i%10].($i>20&&$i%10?" and ":"").["",teen,twenty,thirty,forty,"half third",three,"half fourth",four,"half fifth"][$i/10].($i>49?" times twenty":"")).",";
```

first pick with the Null coalescing operator ?? the exceptions.

this version with 314 Bytes is without the , at the end

```php
zero<?php for($i=0;$i++<100;)echo",".([10=>ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,15=>fifteen,18=>eighteen][$i]??["",one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine][$i%10].($i>20&&$i%10?" and ":"").["",teen,twenty,thirty,forty,"half third",three,"half fourth",four,"half fifth"][$i/10].($i>49?" times twenty":""));?>,one hundred
```

Answer (score 3):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>286</s> 273 bytes

```
zero
-(c){
-c>9 and c<20:
{ten|eleven|twelve|{thir|four|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine}teen}
-c%10:
{&one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine}{c>9: and {t}}
-1:
~temp t="{twenty|thirty|forty|{&half {third|fourth|fifth}|{three|four}} times twenty}"
{t}
}
{c<99:->c}one hundred
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc/NDoIwDAfw@55iMZHogUS8QYR3MaO4RewM1M@tvjqWcTBe2qRbfv3X4Xma3jB4lW/MNqjcNKU@YqvNYb@rVCDACD3cpdED@jvEQNYNsfM3Ka6Lo3vGMb2DO9mIDoEJAFmodbGra1E@BJerpnoVxEB6xZmQ1vm5hswe@04nt00w2Zkmy/OyASANmTW5C4x6MXgl4WRJISEzjyDxfPz9FkCy/oejJV0wTVFW6UgRWLEK5lCWVd4YFkjbG7YDtNP0BQ)

- -13 bytes by removing a useless "five times twenty" case, special-casing zero to be able to simplify the mod check, and simplifying the teens (which now also include ten)

Ink has sequences - they look like `{a|b|c}` and evaluate to a different value each time, until there's no next value at which point they stick with the last one. By combining and nesting these, we can get pretty advanced with very little in the way of actual conditionals.

A sequence that begins with `{&` instead of just `{` is a cycle - those loop and that's how we count units and how we alternate between "half nth times twenty" and "n times twenty" for the tens.

We keep track of the name for the tens in a variable `t` which we only update every tenth pass through the loop. On the passes where we update the variable, we print only the variable, on other passes we use cycles to print the unit followed by `and {t}`.
With a handful exceptions - below ten we skip printing the tens (no `three and zero`) and the teens are irregular enough that they get a sequence all to themselves.

`c` is a labelled gather. Gathers by themselves don't do anything, but they can be diverted to as a form of control flow, and they keep track of how many times they've been visited - we use this readcount to special-case the teens, to know when we need to update the tens variable, and to know when to stop looping, wrap everything up and print one hundred.

I know I could save a byte by using "forth" instead of "fourth", but I'm choosing not to.

### Ungolfed

```
zero // Print "zero"
- (c)
{
- c > 9 and c < 20:
    // The teens get a sequence of their own because they don't fit into the other numbers' pattern.
    {ten|eleven|twelve|{thir|four|fif|six|seven|eigh|nine}teen}
- c % 10: // Otherwise, unless we're meant to print a multiple of ten
    // Print the unit - this is a cycle, so it loops when it's been run through nine times.
    {&one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine}           
    {c > 9:<> and {t}} // If we're past nine (and, since we didn't enter the "teens" section earlier, past nineteen), also print " and " and the contents of the variable t.
- else:
    // Set the variable t to the multiple of ten we want. Note the cycle to alternate between "half nth" and "n"
  ~ temp t="{zero|ten|twenty|thirty|forty|{&half {third|fourth|fifth}|{three|four}} times twenty}"

    {t} // Print the contents of t
}
{c < 99: -> c} // If we've done all this fewer than a hundred times, we go back to the top.
one hundred // Print "one hundred"
// Out of content, end of program
```